# owasp-dependency-check: JavaScript code is not analyzed

Tags: javascript, npm, owasp, owasp-dependency-check

I am trying to use the NPM module [owasp-dependency-check](https://www.npmjs.com/package/owasp-dependency-check) in order to highlight possible vulnerabilities in the code of my web project. I have installed version 0.0.18, the latest.

I want to analyse the custom code I wrote (directory `src`) and the libraries my project depends on (directory `node_modules`).

The task in package.json (section `scripts`) reads:

```
"test:dependency": "owasp-dependency-check --project \"MY_PROJECT\" --scan \"src\" --scan \"node_modules\" --exclude \"dependency-check-bin\" --out \"owasp\" --format HTML"
```

After the launch, it seems that the instructions have been specified correctly:

```
owasp-dependency-check: Running the dependency check ...
/home/workspace/MY_PROJECT/dependency-check-bin/dependency-check/bin/dependency-check.sh --out=owasp --project MY_PROJECT --scan src --scan node_modules --exclude dependency-check-bin --format HTML --data=/tmp/dependency-check-data
```

After about 10 minutes of execution, I find a file `owasp/dependency-check-report.html` with size of 61MB (!?!). I view it in the browser and **it contains the analysis of the sole directory `dependency-check-bin`**, which is the directory where the `owasp-dependency-check` NPM module installs some executables and which I explicitly try to skip in the analysis.

[image: dependency-check-report]

(ironically, there are 6 medium-to-critical vulnerabilities in the libraries that the dependency checker itself uses...)

**My question is: what is wrong with my task definition in package.json? How should I invoke owasp-dependency-check in order to scan `node_modules` and `src`?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer was [given to me by one of the maintainers of the NPM module](https://github.com/etnetera/owasp-dependency-check/issues/3#issuecomment-1090418299).

In the case of JavaScript the scan does not involve directories, but the single `package-lock.json` file.

The correct task definition is therefore:

```
"test:dependency": "owasp-dependency-check --project \"MY_PROJECT\" --scan \"package-lock.json\" --exclude \"dependency-check-bin\" --out \"owasp\" --format HTML"
```